# Check package and its tests build without creating a binary or running the tests

Tags: go

Using Go, how can I check that a package and its tests will build successfully, without running the tests or creating a binary that outlives the check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the command:

```
go test -run @
```

This command compiles the package and tests and starts the test application, but no tests run because no function name matches the regular expression "@".

Comment: That results in the test binary being built and run though.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge The only way to tell if something builds successfully is to build it. This command does not run the tests per the requirement in the question.

Comment: any code in `init` functions, or run to initialise globals will be executed, since that happens before the test program decides what tests to execute.

Comment: @JamesHenstridge Yeah, but that's not what you asked in the question.

Comment: I didn't ask the question.  But if his concern is about running untrusted code, then code in `init` functions is going to be just as much a concern as code within `Test*` functions.